# Request JSON data from URL and send respond out to document

Tags: json, node.js, express, node-request

I am trying to send a request to an API which returns JSON and then show that request in my own url  but when I runs this code it shows that there's respond from API on the console but it can't send it to document usisng res.send I need some help to know where can I send this to the document out not just in the console. One more question am I doing this right or should I use router? Thank you.

```
// Include Express library
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
// Inlcude Request library
var request = require('request')
// Inlcude Http / Https library
var http = require('http')
var https = require('https')

app.use('/postman/tracks', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var carrier = req.query.carrier
    var number = req.query.number
    var url = 'http://api.goshippo.com/v1/tracks/' + carrier + '/' + number
    var response = request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (err,res,obj) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
            //res.send(JSON.stringify(obj))
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: You can use `res.json(obj)` directly

Comment: @MahmoudEzzat I tried that and in the console it said : res.json is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using same variable name `res` for the nested callbacks is the source of your problem , you should update your code to be

```
// Include Express library
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
// Inlcude Request library
var request = require('request')
// Inlcude Http / Https library
var http = require('http')
var https = require('https')

app.use('/postman/tracks', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var carrier = req.query.carrier
    var number = req.query.number
    var url = 'http://api.goshippo.com/v1/tracks/' + carrier + '/' + number
    var response = request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (err, response ,obj) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
            res.json(obj);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks! My mistake

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're overriding `express` `res` with `request` `res` object.

```
app.use('/postman/tracks', function (req, res) {
    //...
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (err,response, obj) { //Changed res with response
        if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
            //res.send(JSON.stringify(obj))
            res.json(obj)
        }
    })
})
```